# Reading a visualization of word embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec, word-embeddings, nlp

For my Masters Thesis, I created a Word2Vec model. I wanted to show this image to clarify the result. But how does the mapping works to display the words in this 2D space?

All words are represented by a vector of 300 dim. How are they mapped on this 2D image? What are the x & y scales?

**Code:**

```
documents = [_text.split() for _text in df_train.text]
w2v_model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(size=W2V_SIZE,
                                            window=W2V_WINDOW,
                                            min_count=W2V_MIN_COUNT,
                                            workers=8)

w2v_model.build_vocab(documents)

words = w2v_model.wv.vocab.keys()
vocab_size = len(words)
print("Vocab size", vocab_size)

w2v_model.train(documents, total_examples=len(documents), 

epochs=W2V_EPOCH)
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df_train.text)

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
print("Total words", vocab_size)

x_train = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_train.text), maxlen=SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
x_test = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_test.text), maxlen=SEQUENCE_LENGTH)

labels = df_train.target.unique().tolist()
labels.append(NEUTRAL)

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(df_train.target.tolist())

y_train = encoder.transform(df_train.target.tolist())
y_test = encoder.transform(df_test.target.tolist())

y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,1)
y_test = y_test.reshape(-1,1)

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, W2V_SIZE))
for word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
  if word in w2v_model.wv:
    embedding_matrix[i] = w2v_model.wv[word]
print(embedding_matrix.shape)
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, W2V_SIZE, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=SEQUENCE_LENGTH, trainable=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the code which shows how you plot the figure above and what you're passing to it so we can get a better idea of the situation.

Comment: @redhqs i added it

Comment: That's still not quite it. I see you've added some code where you process your train/ test sets and prepare the embedding layer, but we can't see how you're creating that plot.